# How to avoid barplot display coverage

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I would like to create a barplot from the following data frame.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(10, 8), sharex=True)

df_A_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Features': ['age', 'weight', 'height', 'waist'],
                              'imp': [0.15, 0.1, 0.07, 0.05]
                              })
df_A_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Features': ['age', 'weight', 'height', 'waist'],
                              'imp': [0.17, 0.12, 0.08, 0.07]
                              })
df_B_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Features': ['Antihypertensive_medication_value', 'KDOSE', 'K', 'ARR_1', 'TG'],
                              'imp': [0.135, 0.107, 0.094, 0.059, 0.079]
                              })
df_B_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Features': ['Antihypertensive_medication_value', 'KDOSE', 'K', 'ARR_1', 'TG'],
                              'imp': [0.15, 0.13, 0.07, 0.06, 0.04]
                              })

sns.barplot('imp', 'Features', data=df_A_1, ax=axes[0, 0], color='lightgrey')
sns.barplot('imp', 'Features', data=df_A_2, ax=axes[0, 1], color='black')

sns.barplot(x='imp', y='Features', data=df_B_1, ax=axes[1, 0], color='lightgrey')
sns.barplot('imp', y='Features', data=df_B_2, ax=axes[1, 1], color='black')
```

[image]

There is one problem here.

Since the Feature (for example, *Antihypertensive_medication_value*) of ax = [0,1] and [1,1] will be covered, is there a way to hide this display?

Comment: TRY this: `axes[0,1].set_yticklabels([]);axes[1,1].set_yticklabels([]);axes[0,1].set_ylabel('');axes[1,1].set_ylabel('')`

Comment: Thank you! I was able to create the ideal diagram.

Comment: In most situations, calling `plt.tight_layout()` at the end of the plotting will automatically adjust the spacing between and around subplots to make everyting fit nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You can change spacing between the plots using [`plt.subplots_adjust()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html)

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(10, 8), sharex=True)

df_A_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Features': ['age', 'weight', 'height', 'waist'],
                       'imp': [0.15, 0.1, 0.07, 0.05]
                       })
df_A_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Features': ['age', 'weight', 'height', 'waist'],
                       'imp': [0.17, 0.12, 0.08, 0.07]
                       })
df_B_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Features': ['Antihypertensive_medication_value', 'KDOSE', 'K', 'ARR_1', 'TG'],
                       'imp': [0.135, 0.107, 0.094, 0.059, 0.079]
                       })
df_B_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Features': ['Antihypertensive_medication_value', 'KDOSE', 'K', 'ARR_1', 'TG'],
                       'imp': [0.15, 0.13, 0.07, 0.06, 0.04]
                       })

sns.barplot('imp', 'Features', data=df_A_1, ax=axes[0, 0], color='lightgrey')
sns.barplot('imp', 'Features', data=df_A_2, ax=axes[0, 1], color='black')

sns.barplot(x='imp', y='Features', data=df_B_1,
            ax=axes[1, 0], color='lightgrey')
sns.barplot('imp', y='Features', data=df_B_2, ax=axes[1, 1], color='black')
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.2, wspace=1.5)
```

[image]

If you want, you can also rename `Antihypertensive_medication_value` to something shorter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One option is to do not repeat your ylabels:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(10, 8), sharex=True, sharey=True)

df_A_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Features' : ['age', 'weight', 'height', 'waist'],
                              'imp': [0.15, 0.1, 0.07, 0.05]
                              })
df_A_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Features' : ['age', 'weight', 'height', 'waist'],
                              'imp': [0.17, 0.12, 0.08, 0.07]
                              })
df_B_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Features' : ['Antihypertensive_medication_value', 'KDOSE', 'K', 'ARR_1', 'TG'],
                              'imp': [0.135, 0.107, 0.094, 0.059, 0.079]
                              })
df_B_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Features' : ['Antihypertensive_medication_value', 'KDOSE', 'K', 'ARR_1', 'TG'],
                              'imp': [0.15, 0.13, 0.07, 0.06, 0.04]
                              })

sns.barplot('imp','Features',data=df_A_1, ax=axes[0, 0], color='lightgrey')
sns.barplot('imp','Features', data=df_A_2, ax=axes[0, 1], color='black')

sns.barplot(x='imp',y='Features', data=df_B_1, ax=axes[1, 0], color='lightgrey')
sns.barplot('imp',y='Features', data=df_B_2, ax=axes[1, 1], color='black')
```

Output:

[image]

Another option is to set a layout, such as follows:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(16, 8), sharex=True, constrained_layout=True)
```

Output:

[image]